# How to print a message when an assert fails, in Dart?

Tags: dart

We'd like to print a message when an `assert()` fails. Currently in Dart, an assert only takes a boolean. We'd like to give the developer explicit reasons and instructions for what to do when the assert fails.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of [Dart 1.22](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1220), `assert()` takes an optional message.

```
assert(configFile != null, "Tool config missing.");
```

If the assertion fails, it will produce something like the following:

```
Unhandled exception:
'file:///.../main.dart': Failed assertion: line 9 pos 10:
'configFile != null': Tool config missing.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:33)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:29)
#2      main (file:///.../main.dart:9:10)
```

Note that the error message includes the actual assertion (`configFile != null`).

Comment: But what if I get a failed assertion in Dart code (UI)? It only prints the error, but I need a stack trace to locate it ...

Answer (score 21):

As filiph said:

```
assert(configFile != null, "Tool config missing.");
```

And to add, if you're executing a dart file via command line, you need to enable asserts as follows, see reference [here](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#assert):

```
dart --enable-asserts main.dart
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an open issue with a workaround https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/6190#issuecomment-119103626

```
assert(() => test || throw "message");
```

I tried this but this way it doesn't work. A slightly modified working version

```
var test = false;
assert(test ? true : throw "message");
```

See also

- https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/core-dev/yNiTFYmtmwY
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24213
- https://github.com/sethladd/dep_assert_with_optional_message/blob/master/proposal.md